# Issue with Raspberry Pi 4 and Monitor Resolution

Tags: pi-4, hardware, display, kali, parrot

I recently got a **raspberry pi 4 (8GB)** and a **1080p** monitor. I have installed **Kali linux 2023.2** and **parrot sec os 5.3** but my **1920x 1080** monitor isn't working with my raspberry pi 4, and keeps defaulting to **1824 x 984** when I run `xrandr -s 1920 x 1080` I get the message `"Size 1920 x 1080 not found in available in modes."` I have tried my screen with a micro SD with **Ubuntu 22.04** installed and it works fine which has led me to believe that this is a problem in settings when using **Kali** and **parrot sec os** but the only option in settings is **1824 x 984** there isn't any other option for screen size and custom profiles don't work either. I tried adding custom screen resolutions using **xrandr** but that doesn't seem to work either. Please check the below attached images of monitor/display.

[IMG_1](https://ibb.co/jRCD4sz)

[IMG_2](https://ibb.co/NnVgtHw)

[IMG_3](https://ibb.co/MnjqfNr)

[IMG_4](https://ibb.co/PwJZwBm)

i fixed this issue in kali linux by editing these 3 lines in `/boot/config.txt`

I commented out the first line, and changed the value of other 2 lines.

```
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82
```

but it raises another issue, mouse doesn't work properly, it gets laggy and pointer moves very slowly on screen and i have to move the mouse too much in order to move the pointer some centimeters on screen, however if i restore original config.txt file then mouse works fine but display again gets messed up

Comment: why are you using Kali Linux? ... it is a specialized distribution not meant for general use

Comment: Please read the section [here](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/#is-kali-linux-right-for-you) titled *Is Kali Linux Right For You?*